# Disable future days at ui.bootstrap.datepicker Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, ui.bootstrap

I am using the [datepicker of UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead):  (there is a [Plunker there](https://plnkr.co/edit/eHw7OGc0Rxw7EGXDHs73?p=previewstrong) that disable the past dayswith a button).

Can anyone please help me to disable the future days without any button?

I tried change the function of the button like that, but it didn't worked:

`$scope.toggleMin = function() {
    $scope.options.minDate = $scope.options.minDate ? **new Date()** : **null** ;
  };`

And this is a button, I'd like to disable without a button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set `maxDate` in `options` to the date you want to restrict to.

```
$scope.options = {
  customClass: getDayClass,
  maxDate: new Date(), // restrict maximum date to today
  showWeeks: true
};
```

Otherwise, if you need to change it after the options are set you can just do:

```
$scope.options.maxDate = new Date(), // restrict maximum date to today
```

Here's the updated Plunker with days after today disabled: https://plnkr.co/edit/0iqNNEcATzv4t8h8n41X?p=preview

Comment: I just refreshed the plunker... I hadn't saved my changes

Answer (score 0):

Set your datepicker class and Set `endDate = new Date()`

```
    $('.date-datepicker').datepicker({
        autoclose: true,
        endDate: new Date()
    });
```